# What moth is this?

Tags: species-identification, entomology, lepidoptera

[image]
[image]
[image]

Location: Rural area near the Western Ghats, Kerala, South India.

Date: Sometime in December, 2016

Climatic Conditions: Humid, frequent rains.

Brief Description:

Couldn't have been bigger than an inch. Took the picture at night. Has characteristic orange stripes across wings and dorsal thorax. A pair of black dots present on either wing; one pair located on the distal region of the wings and another (less conspicuous) pair located on the proximal region of the wings (laterally over thorax). No immediate/visible response when I shone a flashlight at it (eventually moved the torch up to the antennae, still no reaction).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a [red striped tiger moth](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Red-striped%20tiger%20moth&tbm=isch). An initial search hasn't found a picture I'm sure is redistributable, so I've linked a Google image search instead.

The number of spots on the wing seem variable. The pictures show examples with four and six spots as well as two spots.

**Later:**

As discussed [on the Physics Stack Exchange chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/36880639#36880639), this is probably *[Cyana perornata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyana_perornata)*.

Comment: -1'd because biology deals with scientific names; which are based on documented  specimen. The same common/colloquial name can indicate more than 1 things. You would rather put it as a comment. Early acceptance of an incomplete answer hinders the question reach the experts' hand.